# Bootstrap modal dialog does not open

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I copied and pasted modal dialog from bootstrap docs. When I click on the button, a modal should appear. But modal does not open in my page. What is it? Maybe problem with jquery?

But in that snippet i see modal dialog but in my page i cannot see that. When you click on the button, Scroll bar are removed and that`s all

```js
'use strict';

// Listening for clicks on each button

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Pricing example · Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
  <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">Company name</h5>
  <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
    <a class="btn-modal text-dark" href="#">Add product</a>
  </nav>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Sign up</a>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      



        <form>
            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            Price:<br>
            <input type="number" name="price" value="1" id="price"><br><br>
        </form>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-action="ADD_TO_PRODUCT">Add To Product</button>

<div class="actions">

</div>
  <div class="products card-columns">
  </div>

  <h2 class="text-center">Cart</h2>
  <div class="cart">

  </div>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                     asdadssadsadsadsasadsad
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

  <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md">
        <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2019</small>
      </div>
  </footer>

</div>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move these:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and paste them before these tags:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: I think then the problem is the version of Bootstrap and the Jquery that you are importing. I'd suggest using the latest version (Version 4) and it will work. Look at what I did here: https://codepen.io/laurabear/pen/wZoGVQ